# InApp purchases Windows phone 8 using cocos2dx game engine

Tags: windows-phone-8, in-app-purchase, cocos2d-x

I am developing a game using cocos2d-x and I want to port it to Windows phone 8 as well as Android.

I plan to make the game free with in app purchases. But I do not yet know how to do that in windows phone 8 with cocos2d-x.

Has anyone else tried to do it before and succeeded with WP8?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently working on a project that will do that Cocos-2d-x running on Win8 and WinRT. Haven't gotten to the in-app purchase part yet, so don't take this as gospel, but my initial research indicates that it'll need to go through the XAML layer.

The trick isn't the In-App Purchase itself, as Microsoft seem to have the API for that fairly well covered; the trick is getting your Cocos2d-x modules communicating with the XAML layer. Unfortunately, currently nobody has made a good interface between the two, so you'll have to make your own. I'm not looking forward to that myself either.

I assume you need something now. What I can do is point you toward some resources that will help.

[In-App Purchase in a Native C++ App: Windows Phone Dev Center](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/wpapps/en-US/7bee4c28-a123-41f3-a37d-48fe3ccc4dab/inapp-purchase-in-a-native-c-app)

[Trial App and In-App Purchase Sample (Windows 8.1)](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Licensing-API-Sample-19712f1a)